# Can we assign pvc to a pv if it is in Released state?

Tags: kubernetes, persistent-volumes, persistent-volume-claims

Can we assign `Persistent volume claim` to a Persistent Volume after it is in `Released` state?
Tried it but can't

Comment: what is the error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Take a look at the [official documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#reclaiming):

> **Reclaiming**
>
> When a user is done with their volume, they can delete the PVC objects from the > API that allows reclamation of the resource.
>   The reclaim policy for a PersistentVolume tells the cluster what to do
>   with the volume after it has been `released` of its claim. Currently,
>   volumes can either be Retained, Recycled, or Deleted.
>
> **Retain**
>
> The Retain reclaim policy allows for manual reclamation of the resource. When the PersistentVolumeClaim is deleted, the
>   PersistentVolume still exists and the volume is considered “released”.
>   But it is not yet available for another claim because the previous
>   claimant’s data remains on the volume. An administrator can manually
>   reclaim the volume with the following steps.
>
> 1. Delete the PersistentVolume. The associated storage asset in external
>      infrastructure (such as an AWS EBS, GCE PD, Azure Disk, or Cinder
>      volume) still exists after the PV is deleted.
> 2. Manually clean up the
>      data on the associated storage asset accordingly.
> 3. Manually delete the
>      associated storage asset, or if you want to reuse the same storage
>      asset, create a new PersistentVolume with the storage asset
>      definition.

Please let me know if that helped.